# can I use System.Net.Http.HttpClient or System.Net.HttpWebRequest for ICAP services

Tags: .net, http, system.net, icap

I'm trying to write an ICAP client in .Net C#. The ICAP protocol is described as being "HTTP-like"

Has anyone had any success using System.Net.Http.HttpClient or System.Net.HttpWebRequest to invoke ICAP services, or do I have to roll my own layer using sockets?